# simple_form grouped select association gives "undefined method `map'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

In my application, users describe buildings. A user should be able to specify in which neighborhood a building exists using a grouped select. The models look like:

```
class Building
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :neighborhood
end

class Neighborhood
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,         type: String, default: nil
  field :borough,      type: String, default: nil
  field :city,         type: String, default: nil
end
```

Using simple_form, I'm trying to generate a grouped select represent a list of neighborhoods the building might belong to.

```
= building_form.association :neighborhood, as: :grouped_select, collection: Neighborhood.where(city: city), group_method: :borough
```

Which ideally creates something like:

```
Borough #1
  Downtown
  Uptown
Borough #2
  Suburbs
  ...
```

However, I get this error:

```
undefined method `map' for "Borough #1":String
```

It appears it is calling `Neighborhood.borough.map`, and because a String doesn't have a `map` function, it errors out. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've struggled with this for sometime, and unfortunately the intuitive 'Rails' magic I was hoping to get from `association` doesn't seem to exist. It's using the underlying Rails `grouped_collection_select`, which doesn't seem to handle objects/models very well.

Instead, it appears to handle Arrays much better. According to [this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select), the collection input should be in the form of:

```
[
  ['group_name',
    [
      ['item-name','item-value'],
      ['item2-name','item2-value'],
      ...(more items)...
    ]
  ],
  ['group2_name',
    [
      ['item3-name','item3-value'],
      ['item4-name','item4-value'],
      ...(more items)...
    ]
  ],
  ...(more groups)...
]
```

MongoDB models don't lend themselves to this format naturally, so I wrote a helper method on my `Neighborhood` class:

```
def self.grouped_by_borough(city)
  groups = []
  Neighborhood.where(city: city).distinct(:borough).each_with_index do |borough, index|
    groups << [borough, Neighborhood.where(city: city, borough: borough)]
  end
  return groups
end
```

Then my `association` looks like:

```
= building_form.association :neighborhood, as: :grouped_select, collection: Neighborhood.grouped_by_borough(city), group_method: :last, option_key_method: :name, option_value_method: :id
```

This also automatically selects any previously selected neighborhood, which is convenient for 'edit' forms.

If any Rails forms/Mongoid gurus have a cleaner way of handling this, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Wow, you helped me come to the realization that this is not easy. I've been spinning my wheels trying to find a "silver bullet", but your pattern worked for me, thanks!

Comment: I didn't need the `option_key_method`, nor the `option_value_method`.